# Behaviour of electron in double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, double-slit-experiment

In double slit experiment, diffraction pattern is observed due to wave-like behaviour of an electron. However I have also learnt that wave behaviour collapses when we try to find the postion of a particle. Does this mean that if we measure the position of the particle just before it reaches the slit then the pattern formed will magically be two bright bands opposed to the diffraction pattern?

Comment: Before the single slit? I don't think so. Or before one of the double slits?

Comment: If you can determine which slit the electron went through, you will destroy the two-slit interference pattern

Comment: maybe understanding this article will help https://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An (as in ONE) electron does not have a wave-like behavior. Whenever we make a (as in ONE) measurement on an electron, we find that it has an energy, a momentum, a spin direction and an electric charge. That is it. We can never reconstruct waves from only one of these measurements.

What does have wave-like behavior is the quantum mechanical ensemble of many electrons. In particular, if we have a monochromatic source of electrons with identical energy and momenta, then we can describe the behavior of this ensemble with a plane wave. The double slit disturbs the wave function of the ensemble and the outgoing wave function after the slit is not a plane wave any longer, but similar to the pattern observed after an optical double slit. If we further modify this experiment and we make "a measurement" at one of the slits, then we are necessarily changing the energy of the part of the wave function "that is going through that slit" and the outgoing wave function pattern changes, again. That it will "magically become two single slit functions" or "one single slit function" is simply false. What pattern will be visible at the screen depends very much on how we are performing this measurement, but that is just one of the many details that the "idealized" Gedankenexperiment omits.

As a general remark, the double slit experiment is one of the worst examples of physics teaching. It suggests a lot of things that are just not so, e.g. that individual quanta behave like corpuscles and that somehow these corpuscles are showing individual wave-like effects. It makes learning quantum mechanics harder, not easier, because eventually the student will have to remove all of these false ideas from his intuition again.